# Sample accurate real-time pitch shifting algorithm

Tags: fft, pitch, time-frequency, real-time

I am trying to implement a phase vocoder overlap-add pitch shifting algorithm for part of a plugin I'm writing.  I have done this kind of thing offline before and I understand the theory, but this is the first time I've attempted to do realtime processing. This seems to add extra difficulty.

Here's my issue: the audio routing library I'm using gives me 1024 samples of audio at a time, and I must return 1024 samples of supposedly pitch-shifted audio each time.  I know that I can just use some kind of ring buffer or something to cache the samples needed for my overlap-add algorithm, but what do I return the very first time? That is, what do I do with the first 1024 samples of audio I'm given? It seems that with an overlap factor of 4, I would need at least 1792 (256*3 + 1024) samples before I could return my first 1024 samples, because of the overlap requirement.

Am I doomed to just output silence the first go-round, until I get enough samples to actually start doing the algorithm? It doesn't seem ideal to delay the audio, even if only by a couple of milliseconds. I would like it to be sample accurate if at all possible, even if there's a slight drop in quality for the first few windows of data.

thanks in advance

Comment: if your FFT length is 1024, you should be able to return non-zero samples in the first frame of output.  it's just that what would be overlapping over that from the previous frame (and added) would be zero, since there **is** no previous frame when you're processing the "first frame" or some might call it the "0th frame".

Comment: Wow, it seems somewhat obvious now that you say it. I can literally take my routine and just preprocess the "-1st" frame, acting like a frame of all 0s came in before the "0th" frame. Thanks for that!

Comment: Not sure why "sample accurate" is in your question title, as waiting for a buffer of 1024 samples (at 44.1) is over 20 mS delay, even assuming no additional system latencies.